# Como identificar tabela esquerda e direita na execução de múltiplos JOINs no SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

Estou tentando entender como ler a execução de múltiplos INNER JOINs. Se eu faço múltiplos INNER JOINs a minha tabela esquerda permanece a mesma do primeiro INNER JOIN ou a tabela esquerda se torna a tabela resultante desse INNER JOIN?

Fiz um exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b52c/18) para tentar entender quem vira a tabela esquerda. No primeiro INNER JOIN pais é a tabela esquerda e cidade é a tabela direita. Mas no segundo INNER JOIN quem vira a tabela esquerda? Vejo três possibilidades ai:

-pais continua sendo a tabela esquerda; ou
-cidade passa a ser a tabela esquerda; ou
-a tabela que é resultado do inner join de pais e cidade vira a tabela esquerda.

```
 create table pais (
 codigo_pais int primary key,
 nome_pais varchar(50)
);

create table cidade (
  codigo_cidade int primary key,
  nome_cidade varchar(50),
  codigo_pais int
);

create table estado (
  codigo_estado int primary key,
  nome_estado varchar(50),
  codigo_pais int,
  nome_cidade varchar(50),
);



insert into pais values(1,'Brasil');
insert into pais values(2,'Portugal');
insert into pais values(3,'Espanha');

insert into cidade values(1,'Belem',1);
insert into cidade values(2,'Joao Pessoa',1);
insert into cidade values(3,'Aracaju',1);

insert into cidade values(4,'Lisboa',2);
insert into cidade values(5,'Porto',2);
insert into cidade values(6,'Braga',2);

insert into cidade values(7,'esp1',3);
insert into cidade values(8,'esp2',3);
insert into cidade values(9,'esp3',3);

insert into estado values(1, 'Port1', 2, 'Lisboa');
insert into estado values(2, 'Port2', 2, 'Braga');

insert into estado values(3, 'Esp1', 3, 'esp1');
insert into estado values(4, 'Esp2', 3, 'esp2');

insert into estado values(5, 'SE', 1, 'Aracaju');
insert into estado values(6, 'AM', 1, 'Belem');
insert into estado values(7, 'PB', 1, 'Joao Pessoa');insira o código aqui

select nome_pais, c.nome_cidade, e.nome_estado
from pais as p
inner join cidade as c
on p.codigo_pais = c.codigo_pais
inner join estado as e
on e.nome_cidade = c.nome_cidade;
```

Comment: Para o caso do INNER JOIN não faz diferença no resultado final. Mas você sempre pode impor uma determinada ordem com o uso de parênteses.

Comment: Obrigada, eu tinha testado fazendo cada uma das tabelas sendo a tabela esquerda e não tinha obtido resultados diferentes. Então é por isso!